# Seeing high severity vulnerabilities when trying to install database npm packages in cypress

Tags: mysql, cypress, npm-package

I was trying to connect cypress to database by installing

```
'npm i mysql -D'
```

and I got an error '`3 high severity vulnerabilities`'. So I ran

```
npm audit fix
```

then I received the following error messages.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/cypress@8.0.2
npm ERR! Found: cypress@12.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/cypress
npm ERR!   dev cypress@"^12.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer cypress@"^2.1.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from @testing-library/cypress@8.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/cypress
npm ERR!   dev @testing-library/cypress@"^8.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: cypress@9.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/cypress
npm ERR!   peer cypress@"^2.1.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from @testing-library/cypress@8.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/cypress
npm ERR!     dev @testing-library/cypress@"^8.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/rithuraj/.npm/_logs/2023-01-27T00_44_33_190Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rithuraj/.npm/_logs/2023-01-27T00_44_33_190Z-debug-0.log
```

I again tried with

```
'npm i mysql -D  --legacy-peer-deps'
```

But no change. How do I fix this or shall I ignore it?

[image: here is the screenshot of the error message]